# Plotting time vs frequency in matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, spectrum

I am trying to find a way to create a graph that shows an audio wave and its time-frequency data (time on x-axis, wave energy and frequency data on y-axis). I have this code that does it on two separate plots:

```
[audio, fs] = wavread('audio.wav');

subplot(211)
spectrogram(audio,256,200,256,fs,'yaxis')

subplot(212)
wavEnergy=audio(:,1);
time=(1/fs)*length(wavEnergy);
t=linspace(0,time,length(wavEnergy));
plot(t,wavEnergy);
```

and now I need help with 2 things.

First, how do I get the spectrogram time to be in terms of seconds? Right now it graphs with an x-range of 0-340 (labeled 'time') and I know the clip is about 40s long (the other plot properly displays this).

Second, how do I plot them together? I know I can get a matrix from spectrogram but which array do I get from that matrix and how do I convert its timeframe to seconds?

EDIT:

First problem solved, but the graphs are still doing something strange - they both output about 40s of data, but the ranges of the graphs and the offsets of the data are different. The spectrogram goes from 0s-40s but the first .5s shows no data, and the wave plot goes from 0s-45s and the last 5s shows no data. How can I get the ranges and offsets to be the same?

EDIT 2:

I just needed to use `axis tight;` on both subplots

Comment: Aligning these two plots on the same time-base relies on determining the sampling frequency of your data. Based on the parameter you are passing to spectrogram, the sampling frequency is 1000 Hz. Based on your definition of `time = (1/8000)*length(wavEnergy)`, the sampling frequency is 8000 Hz. These are not consistent. To get the audio sampling frequency from your wav file you can use `[audio, fs] = wavread('audio.wav')`. Also, I think your subplot command should be `subplot(2,1,1)` rather than `subplot(211)`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I was able to get the time range correct, but I ran into a new problem as well

Comment: nvm. You basically answered my question - if you turn it into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: glad I could help! If you are needing to plot a lot of spectra for research purposes then you may want to look into MATLAB toolboxes such as [Fieldtrip](http://fieldtrip.fcdonders.nl/) or [Chronux](http://www.chronux.org) which can generate more precise spectral estimates along with statistics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aligning these two plots on the same time-base relies on determining the sampling frequency of your data. Based on the parameter you are passing to spectrogram, the sampling frequency is 1000 Hz. Based on your definition of `time = (1/8000)*length(wavEnergy)`, the sampling frequency is 8000 Hz. These are not consistent. To get the audio sampling frequency from your wav file you can use `[audio, fs] = wavread('audio.wav')`.